# Simple way to find which one are in the same company with me?

Tags: elasticsearch

There is index have field like below, it saves who in which company and which position is

```
{
    "createtime" : 1562844632272,
    "post" : "director",
    "personId" : 30007346088,
    "comId" : 20010774891
 }
```

now want to find the partners of someone, that is which person is in the same company. Now my implementation is

first find the person's related companies(at most 500)

```
{
    "query": { "term": { "personId": 30007346088 } },
    "sort": [ { "createtime": "desc" } ],
    "_source": ["comId"],
    "size":500
}
```

then find these companies' related persons and exclude the current person and remove duplicate partner(similarly at most 500 partners)

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{ "terms": { "comId": [20010774891,...] } } ],
            "must_not": [ {"term":{"personId":30007346088}} ]
        }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "personId" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "personId",
                "size": 500
            }
        }
    },
    "size":0    
}
```

Obviously it's a little complicated, if could exist some more simple way to implement it?

Comment: Your query perfectly translates your need. Why do you think this is complicated?

Comment: because I'm not very proficient at elasticsearch, and compared to sql it's a little complicated, if use sql just one sql could implement it, e.g. `select distinct person_id from t where com_id in (select com_id from t where person_id = 1) and person_id != 1` So want to know if could implement it in one search

Answer (score 1):

It can work if data is stored in below format.

A unique document for each person , with document id same as person id and company stored as array

```
POST indexperson/_doc/1
{
  "createtime": 1562844632272,
  "personId": 1,
  "company": [
    {
      "id": 100,
      "post": "director"
    },
    {
      "id": 100,
      "post": "director"
    }
  ]
}
```

Data:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "indexperson",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "createtime" : 1562844632272,
          "personId" : 1,
          "company" : [
            {
              "id" : 100,
              "post" : "director"
            },
            {
              "id" : 101,
              "post" : "director"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexperson",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "createtime" : 1562844632272,
          "personId" : 2,
          "company" : [
            {
              "id" : 101,
              "post" : "director"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexperson",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "createtime" : 1562844632272,
          "personId" : 3,
          "company" : [
            {
              "id" : 100,
              "post" : "director"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexperson",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "createtime" : 1562844632272,
          "personId" : 4,
          "company" : [
            {
              "id" : 104,
              "post" : "director"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:
Use (terms look up)[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html]. Terms look up takes doc id as parameter

```
GET indexperson/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "company.id": {
              "index": "indexperson",  
              "id": "1", --> get all docs in indexperson which match with company id
              "path": "company.id"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "personId": {
              "value": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "indexperson",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "createtime" : 1562844632272,
          "personId" : 1,
          "company" : [
            {
              "id" : 100,
              "post" : "director"
            },
            {
              "id" : 101,
              "post" : "director"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexperson",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "createtime" : 1562844632272,
          "personId" : 3,
          "company" : [
            {
              "id" : 100,
              "post" : "director"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```